Return 404 instead of 403 to fix security vulnerability "Hidden Directory Detected" in C# .net
I am working on .NET web forms application security scan report that scanned the portal and reported an issue "Hidden Directory Detected".
Risk: It is possible to retrieve information about the site's file system structure, which may help the attacker to map the web site.
The test tried to detect hidden directories on the server. The 403 Forbidden response
reveals the existence of the directory, even though access is not allowed.
The report recommends to issue a "404 - Not Found" response status code for a forbidden resource, or remove it completely.
I have modified web.config file to disable directory browsing and set .
However, to return 404 status code instead of forbidden response, it is required to identify and differentiate whether an authenticated user is accessing resources or an attacker is trying to retrieve the information of site's file system structure .
To fix this issue I tried to implement http handler that can process requests targeted to specific known directory, example "Images" directory and return response status code 404.
[C# handler to return 404 for specific directory access]
public class NoAccessHandler : IHttpHandler
    {

        #region IHttpHandler Members

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get { return true; }
        }

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Request.CurrentExecutionFilePathExtension))            
                context.Response.StatusCode = 404;
        }

        #endregion
    }

Though handler can return 404 response but it would only restrict the access to the specific directory. It needs to be generalized to restrict access to any hidden directory.
[Handler registered in web config]
 <add name="NoAccess" verb="*" path="Images/*"  preCondition="integratedMode" type="NoAccessHandler"/>
</handlers>

If anyone knows more about fixing Hidden Directory Detected vulnerability, suggest a solution that would take care of such malicious attacks and return 404 response code instead of revealing the hidden directories with 403 forbidden message.

What is your threat-model? Is exposing "information about the site's file system structure" actually a problem? I bring these up because there's a lot of snake-oil-salesmen "experts" in cybersecurity who point to some flashy report generated by a tool that they really don't understand...

Issue type is "Hidden Directory Detected", despite directory browsing is disabled on IIS/ web config, attacker is trying to retrieve information about the site's file system structure, which may help the attacker to map the web site.

I wonder why you are having hidden directories under you application folder.

Please include the code as text, see helpful meta-topic.


Modify web.config to Handle All Hidden Directories
You can use the  section in your web.config to handle all 403 errors and return a 404 status code instead. Here’s an example configuration:

<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
        <remove statusCode="403" />
        <error statusCode="403" path="/404.html" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>

This configuration will redirect all 403 errors to a custom 404 page, effectively masking the existence of hidden directories1.

Custom HTTP Module
If you need more control, you can create a custom HTTP module to intercept requests and modify the response status code based on your logic.


This will break all 403 errors, even those where the user is authenticated and the service can return an accurate error.

Other answers equal to this here like this also filter on substatuscode and not only on status code. Some info on substatus 14 here
